# unable to view the cells in the collection which gets created after clicking the menu button

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I have two screens in `storyboard.rootview` screen, just like splash screen and the other is home screen which is created using collection view with header.

In header I am having a `UIButton` by clicking on that I should be able to show menu options for my app which is also a collection view. As I am relatively new to iOS programming i followed [a video in youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PNmuTTd5zWc)

The problem is as per the video I'am able to create a collection view as a subview but after implementing the collecton view func and running the app unable to view the cells which I configured

The code of `viewcontroller.swift` is like this

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegate{
    var tableLabel:[String]=[""]
    var tableImage: [String]=[""]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    let settingLauncher=SettingLauncher()

    @IBAction func menuButtonTaped(sender: UIButton) {

        settingLauncher.showSettings()

    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return tableLabel.count
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell:CellCollectionViewCell=collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("MyCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CellCollectionViewCell
        cell.layer.cornerRadius=10

        cell.labelOne.text=tableLabel[indexPath.row]
        cell.imageOne.image=UIImage(named:tableImage[indexPath.row])
        cell.imageOne.layer.cornerRadius=41
        cell.imageOne.layer.masksToBounds=true
        return cell
    }
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView
    {

        let header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind(UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "HomeHeader", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CellCollectionReusableView

        return header
    }






    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

and `settingLauncher.swift` file is like this

```
import UIKit

class SettingLauncher:NSObject,UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{

    override init() {
        super.init()

        collectionView.dataSource=self
        collectionView.delegate=self

        collectionView.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)


    }

    let blackView=UIView()


    var collectionView:UICollectionView={
        let layout = UICollectionViewLayout()
        let cv=UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        cv.backgroundColor=UIColor.blueColor()
        return cv
    }()

    let cellId="cellId"


    func showSettings() {

     if let window = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow{
        blackView.backgroundColor=UIColor(white: 0,alpha: 0.5)
        blackView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismissShade)))
        window.addSubview(blackView)
        window.addSubview(collectionView)
        let height:CGFloat=200
        let y:CGFloat=window.frame.height-height
        collectionView.frame=CGRectMake(0, window.frame.height, window.frame.width, height)
        blackView.frame=window.frame
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .CurveEaseInOut, animations: {

            self.collectionView.frame=CGRectMake(0, y, self.collectionView.frame.width, self.collectionView.frame.height)
            }, completion: nil)

    }
    }

    func dismissShade(){
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5){

            self.blackView.alpha=0
            if let window = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow{
            self.collectionView.frame=CGRectMake(0, window.frame.height, self.collectionView.frame.width, self.collectionView.frame.height)
            }


        }

    }



    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }



    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(cellId, forIndexPath: indexPath)

        cell.backgroundColor=UIColor.redColor()

        return cell

    }

}
```

the app build succeeded without any errors, but I'm unable to view the cells in the collection which gets created after clicking the menu button

here screen shot before clicking on menu

[image: menu]

here screen shot after clicking on menu

[image: menu]

Comment: show the crash report

Comment: the app is not crashing,unable to view colletionView cells that were created in my settingLauncher Class

Comment: then follow ddb answer

Comment: please see a screen shot linked with the name menu at the staring of my question

Comment: why you are used two collectionviews, whats your requiremnt and if you click this `@IBAction func menuButtonTaped(sender: UIButton) {

        settingLauncher.showSettings()

    }` what you like to do

Comment: slide in menu after tapping button i should be able to show menu options that is my functionality

Comment: ok then why you used two collectionviews in here  , you can directly call view controller view at the same time you are created the array `tableLabel` but never append the data in that array

Comment: in view controller class i have created the base collectionView and created action for button from the base collection view now after tapping the i would like to menu options in another  collection view.and the array i created is for base collection view i would like to populate it once the layout got final

Answer (score 0):

You should set your `collectionView`'s `dataSource` and `delegate` to the viewController in your `ViewController` class (as you did for `SettingLauncher` class).

Comment: in your showSettings() can you try to call self.collectionView.reloadData() ?

Comment: but i tried self.collectionView,reloadData() but the result is same no cells in my collection View

Comment: share some screen shots of the issue

Comment: you have to edit your question and then go down in the text and in the toolbar of the writing form you can see an image icon: if you click it you can upload all images you want

Comment: The empty collectionView is the blue space?

Comment: I think the blue space is a collectionViewCell indeed, as in the collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath: method you are setting blue background. Try to set background color to red for the collectionView in your SettingLauncher class when you show it. Also you are not defining any dimension for the collectionViewCell, so it has a big dimension

Comment: in your code I see that you're applying blue color only to cells, not to collectionview

Comment: ok, after this change do you continue seeing the same image you posted already?

Comment: try removing the implementation of UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout from you class SettingLauncher. it should become "class SettingLauncher:NSObject,UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource{"

Comment: I saw you modified cell background color to red. Now did the blue part of the screenshot become red?

Comment: can you upload your complete source code somewhere and share it in your question? so I can try it in my mac

Comment: for source try this link and download  https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0hLyPMPUWjmOGJ0UlowdUdFX0U

Comment: hi there ,are u able to download the source  and see

Comment: Hi, yes, I downloaded it, but unfortunately it crash at startup on my simulator (I have some problems in my Xcode with simulators from time to time). I see in your code that you created a UICollectionViewCell in the storyboard for the first collectionView, while you are handling the second collectionView differently (you are creating it programmatically, without using a xib or a visual model for its UICollectionViewCell). I suggest you to work in storyboard and create there everything you need (eventually removing the SettingLauncher class and putting everything in your home ViewController)

Comment: is that's the only alternative